# JGit Commit file to remoteRepository without Clone

Tags: java, jgit

I'm new with JGit and I'm trying to checkout a remote branch and commit a file to it. But I stucked here and don't know what to do next:

```
Collection<Ref> branchs = Git.lsRemoteRepository()
                    .setHeads(true)
                    .setTags(true)
                    .setRemote(REMOTE_URL)
                    .setCredentialsProvider(new UsernamePasswordCredentialsProvider(username,password))
                    .call();
Optional<Ref> branch = branchs.stream().filter(r -> r.getName().equals("refs/heads/"+branchName)).findFirst();
```

How can I turn *Ref* to *Repository* or something to use *GitCommand*?
Sorry for my bad English, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works with a remote repository. You need to clone it if you want to perform changes.

```java
Git myGit = Git.cloneRepository()
                    .setURI(REMOTE_URL)
                    .setDirectory(destination)
                    .setCredentialsProvider(new UsernamePasswordCredentialsProvider(username,password))
                    .call();
```

After you have a local copy you can add files to it.

```java
myGit.add().addFilepattern(FILE_PATTERN).call();
```

Changing branches can be done with:

```java
myGit.checkout().setName(branch).call()'
```

Do not forget to commit the changes and push to the remote.